# How can i print a list of arrays in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays

i'm trying to write a program in java to print a list of arrays. I know there's already Array.toString(arr) method, but i don't want the "[..]" on the list. I wrote some simple code to do so.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    int[] v = new int[10000];
    for(int i = 0; i <= t; i++){
            int m = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int list = 0;
            for(int min = m; min < n; min++){
                    if(isPrime(min) == true){
                        v[list] = min;
                        list++;
                    }
                }
            System.out.printf(("%d \n"), list + ("\n \n"));
            }
        }

public static boolean isPrime(int num){
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(num) + 1;
    for(int i = 2; i < sqrt; i++){
        if(num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Say that this is the Input

`1
1 10`

and the Output is

`2
3
5
7`

in this exact order and formatting.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Your code doesn't only print an array of number, it does a lot more. You have a method `isPrime` which probably checks if a number is prime or not. What is your expected output and why you think this code is wrong?

Comment: @AnoopLL What am i doing wrong in my code to get the output i want?

Comment: @AnthonyGayflor what output you want?

Comment: @AnoopLL I posted it in the question but. 2, 3, 5, 7. With out the commas and a new line after each int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will solve your error

```
System.out.printf(("%d \n"), list,( "\n \n"));
```

But if you want to print prime numbers then you need to print `num` instead of `list`

```
for(int min = m; min < n; min++){
                if(isPrime(min) == true){
                    v[list] = min;
                    list++;
                  System.out.printf(("%d \n"), min,( "\n \n"));
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my output problem :). My output is only one number tho and not the list i was wishing for.   `2  3  5  7` Is the output i desire with the given input in the question.

Comment: @AnthonyGayflor what is the output you are getting now?

Comment: Just a 5. Its not printing the list of prime numbers.

Comment: @AnthonyGayflor did you read my answer.. i clearly mentioned that if you need prime numbers then you need to print num not the list and that too inside the if condition...

Comment: @AnthonyGayflor updated my answer.. please make an idea about what you are doing..

Comment: My mistake, i apologize i'm still new to programming and stackoverflow, sorry my communication is awful! That worked like a charm although, thank you!

Comment: @AnthonyGayflor Try to optimize your code.. There is no need of that first for loop. and declaring an array like new int[10000]; is very bad. It will allocate memory to store 10000 integer and you are using very less, in your program you are not at all using it. Best wishes for your learning..